# Reagent, UIkit dropdown use

Tags: uikit, interop, clojurescript, reagent

I am trying to use UIkit dropdown, but with javascript, not with the `uk-dropdown="target: #my-id"`attribute

```
(defn uk-drop []
   [:div 
     [:div#my-id {:data-uk-dropdown true} "Some content"]
     [:button 
          {:on-click #(.show (.dropdown js/UIkit "#my-id"))} 
          "Open"]
     [:button 
          {:on-click #(.hide (.dropdown js/UIkit "#my-id"))} 
          "Close"])
```

Unfortunately this works only once. So it shows the dropdown, then it hides it (or maybe only the click closes it, not the method), but it won't open it again. If I try it from Chrome Console with `UIkit.dropdown("#category1").show()` it works again, but not from the Reagent on-click handler. Any help is appreciated.

Another version I tried after a comment is:

```
(defn uk-drop []
    (let [the-drop (atom nil)] 
    (fn [] 
     [:div
      [:div#my-id {:data-uk-dropdown true} "Some content"
      [:button
       {:on-click #(reset! the-drop (.dropdown js/UIkit "#my-id"))}
       "Make dropdown"]
      [:button
       {:on-click #(.show @the-drop)}
       "Open"]
      [:button
       {:on-click #(.hide @the-drop)}
       "Close"]]])))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn uk-drop []
  (let [the-drop (atom nil)]
    (reagent/create-class
     :component-did-mount (fn [this]
                            (reset! the-drop (.dropdown js/UIkit "#my-id")))
     :reagent-render
      (fn []
        [:div
          [:div#my-id {:data-uk-dropdown true} "Some content"]
          [:button {:on-click #(.show @the-drop)} "Open"]
          [:button {:on-click #(.hide @the-drop)} "Close"]]))))
```

I haven't tried this, but you probably need to create the dropdown object only once after componnet is mounted, so you need reagent form-3 component, it allows you to use react lifecycle hooks. I am not familiar with UIkit, so this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

if there's something stateful in the JS call, then getting the result of calling `(.dropdown js/UIkit ...)`, storing it as part of your app state and passing it into your component might help.

Comment: Well, I used another version as well, where I first make an atom **(let [the-drop (atom nil)])**,  And first I do **(reset! the-drop (.dropdown js/UIkit "#my-id"))**, and then **{:on-click #(.show @the-drop)}**, but it still works only one time. How do I make it stateful if not like that? :/

Comment: I updated my question, I hope I am closer to the solution, I don't know how to update the stored result of the .dropdown method